# SSH remote using XQuartz dosent work in Lion

Tags: macos, ssh, xquartz

I was using previous version of Mac and used to connected to a server with SSH console.It used to run X 11 after loading my requested programs(Mathematica) on remote server and was working properly.Recently I upgraded my Mac to the latest version(Mountain Lion 10.8.4) and this SSH is not loading the "X" and I can not use remote access to my requested program from remote server.How can I fix the problem.Please in a easy way because I am not in using Mac commands at all.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean X11, the display manager?  if so, it was deprecated, and you will need to download and install it seperately as it is no longer included in OS X.

Comment: @stuffe hi many thanks I installed X11 but this time the Java jives Authentication error after I want to run my required module in SSH console.What could be wrong?

Comment: Not sure, it might be worth asking a fresh question for this - I will add my comment as an answer, because it was just a quess before.

Comment: → Alex: please edit your original post. As noted by Stuffe, `X 10` doesn't mean a lot to many of us (except the survivors who knew this version of the X Window System ☺).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this page, X11/XQuartz is deprecated from OS X now, and you will need to install it seperately in order to get any X-Windows display manager type stuff working:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293

There seems to be another X11 download here which may also be useful.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/X11_for_Mac_OS_X_1_0